# Forcing HTTPS & NON-WWW on a subfolder with a different domain rewrites incorrectly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, no-www

I already have a Wordpress website installed to `/home/USER/public_html/` and the `.htaccess` inside the folder looks like:

```
# BEGIN Redirect Alias Site to Specific Folder
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} customwebsite.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /customwebsite/$1 [L]
# END Redirect Alias Site to Specific Folder

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The redirect alias rules in the `.htaccess` file above allows me to route my alias domain to use a different folder thus allowing mulitple websites to be ran from the same cPanel account.

In the folder `/home/USER/public_html/customdomain/` I've set the `.htaccess` rules to:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /customdomain/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /customdomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It works perfectly fine; however if I try and FORCE HTTPS and NON-WWW using every set of rules I can find on the internet... for example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force HTTPS & NON-WWW
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^customdomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://customdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

and what I can make myself and then try and load any of the following:

- `http://customdomain.com`
- `https://www.customdomain.com`
- `http://www.customdomain.com`

They all redirect to:

- `https://customdomain.com/customdomain/`

Which is partly correct, but partly wrong. It shouldn't have the folder at the end of the domain which causes problems because the URL is now incorrect.

Sure if I remove the `%{REQUEST_URI}` it fixes the redirect issue but if I am using Wordpress for example every URL will be wrong and will throw up a 404 page not found.

How can I fix the Force HTTPS & NON-WWW to allow for this scenario?

Comment: At present, if you enter `https://customdomain.com/page` where `page` is a valid page on `customdomain` site. Does it load correct page?

Comment: Yes, if /page/ was a valid page it loads correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule **as your first rule in `/customdomain/.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /customdomain/

# Force HTTPS & NON-WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^customdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://customdomain.com/$0 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.